# R change chr to dttm and dateTime format

Tags: r, chr

Have been trying for days to convert a chr column in the format of dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM into dttm in the format of yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.

nothing works and I keep getting NA as the output as it "failed to pharse"

started with

```
$ started_at         <chr> "30/5/2021 11:58", "30/5/2021 11:29", "30/5/2021 14:24",~
<br>$ ended_at           <chr> "30/5/2021 12:10", "30/5/2021 12:14", "30/5/2021 14:25",~
```

**entered this**

```
tripdata_202105_processed[['started_at']] <- ymd_hms(tripdata_202105_processed[['started_at']])
```

**and got this**

> All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
>
> $ started_at          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,~
>
> $ ended_at            "30/5/2021 12:10", "30/5/2021 12:14", "30/5/2021 14:25",~

really exhausted whatever i could have do myself, really appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is day/month/year hour:minute, so we use `dmy_hm` where `d` is `day`, followed by `m` for `month`, `y` for `year` and `h` for `hour` and `m` for `minute`

```
library(lubridate)
dmy_hm(tripdata_202105_processed[['started_at']])
```

For multiple columns, we can use `across`

```
library(dplyr)
tripdata_202105_processed <- tripdata_202105_processed %>%
    mutate(across(c(started_at, ended_at), dmy_hm))
```

Comment: Not sure if you get what im asking for, i wanna change the data type from chr to dttm and the format from dmy HM to ymd HMS

Comment: @BenZenoVKa yes, i got it.  the code converts to POSIXct where the default format is `ymd HMS` i.e. `dmy_hm("30/5/2021 11:58")#
[1] "2021-05-30 11:58:00 UTC"`